# Transfering daily values from one sheet into another shee

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new to coding and I am trying to build this within Google Sheets (Apps Script).

I have a sheet that returns values for about 20 different variables on a once day basis.  I would like to copy each value (not the variable) into another sheet (effectively starting a small database).  The list of variables may differ from day to day, but the (target) other sheet will have all the variables listed across all the colums in row 1, and the script should paste the values in the appropriate column heading.

Example:

Sheet 1 (source) will look like this in side by side columns.

```
 Variable 1   Value 1
 Variable 2   Value 2
 Variable 3   Value 3
```

Copy and paste them the values into another sheet (target) that will look something like this.

```
         Variable 1     Variable 2   Variable 3.... etc...                               
Day 1    Value 1        Value 2      Value 3
```

and then on the next day, it will add onto the last available row under each appropriate heading.

```
           Variable 1     Variable 2   Variable 3..... etc...
  Day 1    Value 1        Value 2      Value 3
  Day 2    Value 1        Value 2      Value 3
```

and if on any particular day there is no value for a specific variable, then just paste 0.

```
          Variable 1     Variable 2   Variable 3..... etc...
 Day 1    Value 1        Value 2      Value 3
 Day 2    Value 1        Value 2      Value 3
 Day 3    0              Value 2      Value 3
```

Lastly, the order of the variables may chance from day to day (source), so the script has to be able not just copy and paste them directly, it has to read and understand which column it needs to get placed in.

Thank you very much in advance.

I have been using Bard to help me (again brand new to this), but the code it offers tends to prompt out with syntax issues that I frankly do not understand.

Here is the code that I adjusted... followed by the error message (thank you)

```
function copyVars() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sh = ss.getSheetByName("**** ****");//input sheet
const vs = sh.getRange(8, 6, 20, 2).getDisplayValues();
const osh = ss.getSheetByName("*****");//output sheet
const pos = osh.getRange(1, 1, 1, 
osh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().flat().reduce((a, h, i) => { a[h] = i + 1; return a; }, {});
let nr = osh.getLastRow() + 1;
vs.forEach((r, i) => osh.getRange(nr, pos[r[0]]).setValue(r[1]));
 }
```

7:15:07 PM  Error
Exception: The parameters (number,null) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange.
(anonymous) @ copyVars.gs:8
copyVars    @ copyVars.gs:8

Answer (score 0):

**Transferring data to new sheet under appropriate columns**

```
function copyVars() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//input sheet
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, 20, 2).getDisplayValues();
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//output sheet
  const pos = osh.getRange(1, 1, 1, osh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().flat().reduce((a, h, i) => { a[h] = i + 1; return a; }, {});
  let nr = osh.getLastRow() + 1;
  vs.forEach((r, i) => osh.getRange(nr, pos[r[0]]).setValue(r[1]));
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Array.methds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

If they were always going to remain together then you could use setValues() however if they have other data and formula then they could easily be corrupted by using setValues();

Sheet0:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 |
| 2 | Var1 | 2 |
| 3 | Var2 | 3 |
| 4 | Var3 | 4 |
| 5 | Var4 | 5 |
| 6 | Var5 | 6 |
| 7 | Var6 | 7 |
| 8 | Var7 | 8 |
| 9 | Var8 | 9 |
| 10 | Var9 | 10 |
| 11 | Var10 | 11 |
| 12 | Var11 | 12 |
| 13 | Var12 | 13 |
| 14 | Var13 | 14 |
| 15 | Var14 | 15 |
| 16 | Var15 | 16 |
| 17 | Var16 | 17 |
| 18 | Var17 | 18 |
| 19 | Var18 | 19 |
| 20 | Var19 | 20 |
| 21 | Var20 | 21 |

Sheet1:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Var1 | Var20 | Var3 | Var4 | Var5 | Var6 | Var7 | Var8 | Var19 | Var10 | Var11 | Var12 | Var13 | Var14 | Var15 | Var16 | Var17 | Var18 | Var9 | Var2 |
| 2 | 2 | 21 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 20 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 10 | 3 |

If I understood your question then I think this is what you require:

```
function copyVars() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//input sheet
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, 20, 3).getDisplayValues().map(([a,b,c])=> [a,c]);
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//output sheet
  const pos = osh.getRange(1, 1, 1, osh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().flat().reduce((a, h, i) => { a[h] = i + 1; return a; }, {});
  let nr = osh.getLastRow() + 1;
  vs.forEach((r, i) => osh.getRange(nr, pos[r[0]]).setValue(r[1]));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Cooper... I will dive into the script to see if i can find the right cell references... cannot thank you enough. If I have any an issue, would you mind if I had a follow up question (I promise to keep it to 1 - maybe 2).

Comment: No problem I'll be around

Comment: I adjusted the script to reflect the correct cells to start the evaluation and I get the follow message.... script used below that...

Comment: 6:51:11 PM Error 
Exception: The parameters (number,null) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange.
(anonymous) @ Transfer.gs:8
copyVars @ Transfer.gs:8

Comment: function copyVars() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Dash Main");//input sheet
  const vs = sh.getRange(8, 6, 20, 2).getDisplayValues();
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Dest2");//output sheet
  const pos = osh.getRange(1, 1, 1, osh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().flat().reduce((a, h, i) => { a[h] = i + 1; return a; }, {});
  let nr = osh.getLastRow() + 1;
  vs.forEach((r, i) => osh.getRange(nr, pos[r[0]]).setValue(r[1]));
}sorry for the repeat posts

Comment: Please post your code into you question.  It will maintain the formatting much better.

Comment: What does your output sheet look like? You seem to be missing the locations of your headers.  Mine were on the top as shown in the table for Sheet1. Be sure to redact private information.

Comment: It mirrors your exactly, and strangely it works now , but in the editor I keep on getting that error message.  I do not want to bug you anymore,or clog the thread - very thankful, I will figure it out.

Comment: It's okay can you share an image of the sheet

Comment: Is you header on row one?

Comment: Oh the other thing I thought I'd mention is that if you are using arrayformulas then that can cause difficulties with google apps script.  Not sure if that will help.

Comment: I lied, one more if I may? Same scenario as above, but how do I adjust if I want to instead of the in the grabbing the value in row B to transpose, there is also a column C and that value I would like to copy over - effectively skipping a column ... Thanks so much..